# Data type of Clock signals

Tags: system-verilog

I've read a standard that says:

> "Logic type signals add a tick delay".

- What does the above statement mean?
- And why is the logic type signal adding a tick delay?

Comment: I'm not familiar with verilog, but could this just be related to the intrinsic input-to-output delay of a logic unit?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'tick' delay in (System) Verilog. You have delta delays but if your code does not work because of delta delays you have written some awfully wrong code.

Comment: They are talking about delta delays in simulation.

Comment: Could you cite, preferably with a link, the specific standard containing that quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilog has a feature called "port collapsing". When you make a port connection and both sides of the connection are wires, The compiler may collapse the two wires into a single wire; the hierarchy gets flattened out. One of the effects you might see from this is when you `force` one side of the connection, both sides get forced.

But if one or both sides is a variable, the compiler inserts an implicit continuous assignment between the two sides. This is an extra event, not really a delay.

And this is also why only wires, not variables, can connect to `inout` ports. There is no such thing as a bi-directional continuous assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The person who wrote that standard didn't know what he was talking about.

The module hierarchy in any HDL is just declarative statements about the topology (connectivity) of a circuit. It has no effect whatsoever on any physical implementation (synthesis) or even simulation.